# How do you fill the entire notification pop up with desired background color (Similar to adidas Running app)?

Tags: android

I would like to achieve the following effect, with a custom view.

[image]

1. Fill color for the entire notification background.
2. Have action button.

I have tried several approaches. None of them work.

---

### No style applied. Apply custom view and custom big view

```
private void initRemoteViews(String timerText) {
    if (remoteViews == null) {
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                PomodoroApplication.instance().getPackageName(),
                PomodoroOptions.INSTANCE.getWorkColor().widgetTimerResourceId
        );
    }

    if (bigRemoteViews == null) {
        bigRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                PomodoroApplication.instance().getPackageName(),
                PomodoroOptions.INSTANCE.getWorkColor().widgetBigTimerResourceId
        );
    }

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, timerText);
    bigRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, timerText);

}

private void initPendingIntents() {
    final Context context = PomodoroApplication.instance().getApplicationContext();

    if (this.mainPendingIntent == null) {
        final android.content.Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, TimerActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(getPreventDoubleLaunchFlagsForLauncher());
        this.mainPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                mainIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );
    }

    if (this.pausePendingIntent == null) {
        Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(context, PauseBroadcastReceiver.class).setAction(PauseBroadcastReceiver.PAUSE_ACTION_NAME);
        this.pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                pauseIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );
    }
}

private Notification createNotification(long currentDuration) {
    String timerText = Utils.getTimerText(
            getMaxDuration(),
            currentDuration
    );

    initPendingIntents();
    initRemoteViews(timerText);

    final Context context = PomodoroApplication.instance().getApplicationContext();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context,
                Utils.createTimerChannel()
        )
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentIntent(mainPendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSound(null)
            .setVibrate(null)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    
    NotificationCompat.Action pauseAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(
            0, context.getString(R.string.pause), pausePendingIntent
    );

    builder.addAction(pauseAction);

    builder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);
    builder.setCustomBigContentView(bigRemoteViews);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    return notification;
}
```

### Outcome

[image]

**This is not what I want, as it doesn't have action button**

---

### Apply NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle style. Apply custom view and custom big view

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
builder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);
builder.setCustomBigContentView(bigRemoteViews);
```

### Outcome

[image]

**This is not what I want, as not entire background is being filled with color.**

---

### Apply MeidaStyle style. Apply custom view and custom big view

```
androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle mediaStyle = new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle();
builder.setStyle(mediaStyle);
builder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);
builder.setCustomBigContentView(bigRemoteViews);
```

### Outcome

[image]

**This is not what I want, as it doesn't have action button**

---

Any suggestion, on how to implement thing similar to **adidas Running** is very much appreciated.

At first glance, **adidas Running** is very closed to `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` style, but with entire background color filled, and correct foreground font color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any custom style. Instead, you need to use [`setColorized(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setColorized(boolean)) on your `NotificationCompat.Builder` to colorize the entire notification.

As per the documentation:

> Set whether this notification should be colorized. When set, the color set with [`setColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setColor(int)) will be used as the background color of this notification.
>
> This should only be used for high priority ongoing tasks like navigation, an ongoing call, or other similarly high-priority events for the user.
>
> For most styles, the coloring will only be applied if the notification is for a foreground service notification.

Comment: Cool! As my prior experience with `setColorized` is with normal priority notification (which seems does nothing). Seem like `setColorized` on foreground service notification yields different behaviour. A quick check: Is it ever possible to apply gradient drawable on **entire** notification background? If not, guess I will just stay with plain color.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - as per the documentation I specifically quoted, it is expected that a foreground service notification is treated differently, yes. No, you can only use a plain color, not a gradient.